# The classes implemented here are proper?

Tags: java

I have below two classes. IS the implementation proper?

```
public class A {

     private String name;
     private String age;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }



}


public class B extends A {

    public B(A a){
        this.setAge(a.getAge());
        this.setName(a.getName());
    }

    public void doSomeThing(){

        //do something with age and name data
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *proper* in what terms?

Comment: You're "effectively" getting the value from name and setting back to it. It really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is my design correct or do you recommend any suggestions?

Comment: What is really you trying to achieve???

Comment: Your constructor in `B` does nothing in reality. Getting a value from a variable and setting it back to itself really doesn't make sense whatsoever.

Comment: why have to create an A object every time I create a B object?!

Comment: Proper in which sense? You are having a class with a copy constructor. I think you wants to add some extra functions in a class which is already written.

Comment: If you in both cases will create a B object why you don't do that :

    ``B b=new B();
    b.setAge(somValue);
    b.setName(somValue);.....`` and void an extra ``A`` object

Comment: Clients will use only A class. They instantiate A class and populate with data .Now i need to pass this data to B.B can have its own properties. The only intention here is doSomeThing() method and few properties of B should not be exposed to clients. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Of course in some case your choice is normal, but the following solution is more "classic":

```
class A {
    private String name;
    private String age;

    A(String name, String age) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
    }

    // getters, setters
}

class B extends A {
    private String c;
    public B(String a, String b, String c){
        super(a, b);
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void doSomeThing(){
        //do something with age and name data
    }
    //getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Ashot, instead of public B(String a, String b, String c) can i use public B(A a, String c) ?

Comment: Can of course, but the instance B is also an instance of type A, and has access to A properties` a and b. So providing their is a little strange. But take a look in  `java.io.*` package. They do something like it: `public BufferedInputStream(InputStream in)` .

Comment: It is a pattern `Decorator` from GOF.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the constructor in class B, since class B already has the properties from class A.

```
public class B extends A {

    public void doSomeThing(){
        //do something with age and name data
        // You can use getAge() and getName() here directly:
        System.out.println(getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: clients will use only A class. They instantiate A class and populate with data .Now i need to pass this data to B. Thanks!

Comment: So, you will be working with class B and you need in fact to copy the A class data from the clients to your B class? In that case you are using a copy constructor which I don't think is a bad idea.